# Java Sort, default sort function working only

Tags: java

I'm sorry to bother, I just started trying to learn to code by my own.
I set myself a task to practice my basics. I'm supposed to generate random ints to populate an Array size 10, after that I have to sort it, look for the min, max and average value of all of the ints in the array and tell if the number 25 is in the array.

As you can see, the idea is to practice array manipulation and I'm not supposed to use built in functions.

So far I've written a method for assigning the random numbers to the array and another one to sort it (bubble sort, since is what I'm trying to learn).
Unfortunately I'm not able to sort the array by calling my sorting method (mySort) if I write the sorting algorithm myself.

If I use the built-in function for sorting inside my sorting method and then call it, it works perfectly. So I guess that means my algorithm is wrong.
I hope you guys could guide me and illuminate me as to what I'm doing wrong.

```
    public static int randomNum;

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        generateRandomNumber(myArray);

        mySort(myArray);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));



    }

    private static int[] generateRandomNumber(int[] myArray) {
        Random numberGenerator = new Random(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            randomNum = numberGenerator.nextInt(100);
            myArray[i] = randomNum;

        }

        return myArray;
    }

    private static void mySort(int[] myArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length -1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < myArray.length- i -1; i++) {
                if (myArray[j] < myArray[j - 1]) {
                    int temp = myArray[j - 1];
                    myArray[j - 1] = myArray[j];
                    myArray[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

if I change to this:

```
 private static void mySort(int[] myArray) {
       Arrays.sort(myArray);

   }

}
```

it works perfectly

Comment: As a starting point, I would look very closely at `for (int j = 1; j < myArray.length- i -1; i++) {`

Comment: Could you also add exactly what is not working well? Does the order of your elements change? how? in what way?

Comment: I think you should not increase i++ in both loops, however this is just a quick thought.

Comment: I'm also not very convinced about this "randomNumberGenerator". It seems every time I execute your code, it uses the exact same "random" numbers.

Comment: Stultuske, it returns the same array, unsorted.

Comment: @Stultuske you are totally right. Seems like deleting MAX VALUE from '''new Random(Integer.MAX_VALUE)''' fixes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your sorting code. The corrected version looks like this:

```
private static void mySort(int[] myArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { // Removed -1
        for (int j = 1; j < myArray.length - i; j++) { // Removed -1, corrected from i++ to j++
            if (myArray[j] < myArray[j - 1]) {
                int temp = myArray[j - 1];
                myArray[j - 1] = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `-1` is not required since you use *less than* (`<`) in your loop condition. That means `i` or `j` will never exceed `array size - 1`.

Comment: also, the myArray doesn't need to be passed as a variable, since it's a static variable. The same with generateNumbers, it should be avoid method just changing the current array, there's no need to pass a param, nor to return an array

Comment: @Stultuske while it doesn't need to be, it should be. The sort method is a completely isolated piece of code which doesn't need to have any coupling to the wrapping class.

Comment: ok. considering the current code, how do you think the mySort method would work as "without coupling"?

Comment: @Stultuske The current code is already completely decoupled. Since myArray is passed by reference, the method will modify the passed in array. No need to return anything or change static members.

Comment: @JensV Wow, thank you for the explanation, that really helps. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work by making following changes to mySort function:

```
private static void mySort(int[] myArray) {
for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.length -1; i++) {// <= instead of <
        for (int j = 1; j <= myArray.length- i -1; j++) {//j++ not i++ and do not miss =;
            if (myArray[j] < myArray[j - 1]) {
                int temp = myArray[j - 1];
                myArray[j - 1] = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the inner loop, you are iterating over i instead of j. Fix it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those annoying little pains in the ... code, which will haunt you

Start by taking a very, very close look at ....

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length -1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < myArray.length- i -1; i++) {
```

Can't see it? Look more closely at the second line...

```
for (int j = 1; j < myArray.length- i -1; i++) {
```

`j` is **always** `1` ... but why?  Because you increment `i` in both loops

If you change the to something more like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length -1; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < myArray.length- i -1; j++) {
```

you should find it fixes the issue